# heat transfer for spherical coordinates boundary conditions implementation

Tags: r, matlab, geometry, boundary, heat

I want to apply heat transfer ( heat conduction and convection) for a hemisphere. It is a transient homogeneous heat transfer in spherical coordinates. There is no heat generation. Boundary conditions of hemisphere is in the beginning at Tinitial= 20 degree room temperature. External-enviromental temperature is -22 degree. You can imagine that hemisphere is a solid material. Also, it is a non-linear model, because thermal conductivity is changing after material is frozen, and this is going to change the temperature profile.

I want to find the temperature profile of this solid during a certain time until center temperature reach to -22 degree.

In this case, Temperature depends on 3 parameters : T(r,theta,t). radius, angle, and time.

1/α(∂T(r,θ,t))/∂t =1/r^2*∂/∂r(r^2(∂T(r,θ,t))/∂r)+ 1/(r^2*sinθ )∂/∂θ(sinθ(∂T(r,θ,t))/∂θ)

I applied finite difference method using matlab, However, boundary conditions have issues. There are convection on surface of the hemisphere, and conduction in the inner nodes, bottom of the hemisphere has constant temperature which is air temperature (-22). You can see the scripts which i am using for BCs in the matlab file.

```
% Temperature at surface of hemisphere solid boundary node

  for i=nodes
       for j=1:1:(nodes-1) 

Qcd_ot(i,j)=   ((k(i,j)+ k(i-1,j))/2)*A(i-1,j)*(( Told(i,j)-Told(i-1,j))/dr);         % heat conduction out of node

Qcv(i,j) =   h*(Tair-Told(i,j))*A(i,j); % heat transfer through convectioin on surface

Tnew(i,j)         =   ((Qcv(i,j)-Qcd_ot(i,j))/(mass(i,j)*cp(i,j))/2)*dt + Told(i,j);

      end       % end of for loop
     end

   % Temperature at inner nodes

   for i=2:1:(nodes-1)     
      for j=2:1:(nodes-1)  


 Qcd_in(i,j)=   ((k(i,j)+ k(i+1,j))/2)*A(i,j) *((2/R)*(( Told(i+1,j)-Told(i,j))/(2*dr)) + ((Told(i+1,j)-2*Told(i,j)+Told(i-1,j))/(dr^2)) + ((cot(y)/(R^2))*((Told(i,j+1)-Told(i,j-1))/(2*dy))) + (1/(R^2))*(Told(i,j+1)-2*Told(i,j)+ Told(i,j-1))/(dy^2));

 Qcd_out(i,j)=  ((k(i,j)+ k(i-1,j))/2)*A(i-1,j)*((2/R)*(( Told(i,j)-Told(i-1,j))/(2*dr)) +((Told(i+1,j)-2*Told(i,j)+Told(i-1,j))/(dr^2)) + ((cot(y)/(R^2))*((Told(i,j+1)-Told(i,j-1))/(2*dy))) + (1/(R^2))*(Told(i,j+1)-2*Told(i,j)+ Told(i,j-1))/(dy^2));


 Tnew(i,j)     =   ((Qcd_in(i,j)-Qcd_out(i,j))/(mass(i,j)*cp(i,j)))*dt + Told(i,j);



    end            %end  for loop
end                % end  for loop


   %Temperature for at center line nodes
  for i=2:1:(nodes-1)
      for j=1

     Qcd_line(i,j)=((k(i,j)+ k(i+1,j))/2)*A(i,j)*(Told(i+1,j)-Told(i,j))/dr;

     Qcd_lineout(i,j)=((k(i,j)+ k(i-1,j))/2)*A(i-1,j)*(Told(i,j)-Told(i-1,j))/dr;

     Tnew(i,j)= ((Qcd_line(i,j)-Qcd_lineout(i,j))/(mass(i,j)*cp(i,j)))*dt + Told(i,j);

      end 
 end


    % Temperature at bottom point (center) of the hemisphere solid
    for i=1
        for j=1:1:(nodes-1)

       Qcd_center(i,j)=(((k(i,j)+k(i+1,j))/2)*A(i,j)*(Told(i+1,j)-Tair)/dr);


       Tnew(i,j)= ((Qcd_center(i,j))/(mass(i,j)*cp(i,j)))*dt + Told(i,j);

      end
  end

   % Temperature at all bottom points of the hemisphere

     Tnew(:,nodes)=-22;


    Told=Tnew;

    t=t+dt;
```

Tnew temperatures values are getting bigger exponentially after program is run, and then becoming NaN. It supposed to show me cooling and freezing temperature profile of solid until it reaches to Tair temperature. I could not figure out the reasons why it is changing like that.

I would like to hear your suggestions for BCs implementation to this program, or how should i change them according to this conditions.  Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Honestly for me, this forum does not sound appropriate to ask such pinpoint question. I am also a thermal engineer. Superfically, it looks that you may have an implementation error: A bug or mistake with differentiation

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too long to read and understand completely, but it looks like you are using a simple [forward Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_Euler_method) scheme, is that correct? If so, try to reduce the time-step `dt`, maybe by a lot, since this method can become numerically [unstable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_Euler_method#Numerical_stability) if `dt` is too big. This might slow down the speed of the computation (again by a lot), but that is the price you pay for such a simple algorithm. There are [alternatives methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method) that do not suffer from instability, but they are much harder to implement, since you need to solve a system of equations.

I did some thermal simulations using this simple scheme a long time ago. I found that the stability criteria was `dt < (dx)^2 * c_p * rho / (6 * k)`, which should be valid for a simulation on a 3D cartesian grid, where `dx` is the spatial step, `c_p` is the specific heat, `rho` the density and `k` the thermal conductivity of the material. I don't know how to convert this to your case with spherical coordinates. The thing I learned then was to choose small time-steps, but more importantly as large `dx` as possible: when you reduce `dx` by a factor 2, you also need to reduce `dt` by a factor 4 to keep things stable. At the same time, for a 3D problem, the number of elements will increase by a factor 8. So the total simulation time scales with `1 / (dx)^5`!!!

Comment: Yes. I am using forward euler scheme.  My time step is dt=0.01 . When i tried to reduce times-step (dt=0.001), it takes such a long time to calculate even this time step it did not give me correct results and getting larger by exponentially. I would like to try alternative methods, Crank-Nicholson method.  However, i am not really know how to apply it to these spherical coordinates system for 2D ( i and j) model.

Comment: Most of the samples are based on 1D finite difference. Also, i feel that implementation of crank nicholson method to matlab for 2D is harder than this forward euler scheme. Do you have any suggestion or samples which is applied for 2d coordinates with Crank nicholson method, which i may implement to my matlab scripts. Thanks in advance for your replies !!

Comment: I don't have an example for CN, google is your friend. Euler is easy to implement for some quick and dirty problem in which you don't mind to use a 'brute-force' calculation. For anything serious, you probably need commercial software like ansys or comsol, which should use the better algorithms. Did you try to increase `dx`? And did you use my formula to see if you fulfill the stability criteria? Problem in your case might be that in spherical coordinates, the central element is very small, so potentially unstable, while the outer elements might be big enough to be stable.